# C: Invalid results when using few pow functions in the same expression

Tags: c, tcc

For some unknown to me reason this code produces different results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main() {
    double y, y2;

    y = pow(2.0, 1.0) * pow(2.0, 1.0) * pow(2.0, 1.0);
    y2 = pow(2.0, 3.0);

    printf("%lf\n", y); // 2.000000
    printf("%lf\n", y2); // 8.000000

    return 0;
}
```

I am using tcc compiler and i guess this might matter since but i can't find any info about such problems.

Comment: The program displays `8.000000` twice on my machine. Are you sure you're running exactly the code you posted?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I just checked it.

Comment: Could you post the full command you're using to compile/run it?

Comment: tcc aaa.c              where aaa.c is the name of the file

Comment: to run i simply write aaa

Comment: I was using `-run`, but I'm still getting 8 twice even by compiling and running separately. Could you compile the code with another compiler (such as gcc or clang) and report the output?

Comment: I ran this code with Dev-C++ and the now both results equal 8. I don't know what's the problem with tcc though.